# I could not able to setup the environment for appium

Tags: testing, automated-tests, appium

I could not able to setup the environment for appium,

Is there any video or clear docs to setup and run a sample test code in appium. ASAP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by _not able_? What error or problem do you have?

Comment: I am fresher for the apppium . i am trying to test the apk file.

i am following the steps from ,
https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/running-on-windows.md


Is that the right way to start?